# How to stop a command in R in Windows

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm using Rstudio in Windows. There is no red octagon for me to click on. I've tried pressing ESC and Ctrl + C and Ctrl + Z in the console but none of those worked.

Comment: ESC usually works for me. But if there is no red octagon, this may mean that R (or RStudio) is not working correctly...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When running a code, the red octagon will only show while it is working things out. So while it is just running through your written code (reading data and names of things etc) then the octagon will not show.

Pressing `ESC` will work, unless Rstudio is frozen.

Good luck!

Answer (score 6):

You could also try interrupting/terminating the R session via the menu:
`Session` -> `Interrupt R`
or
`Session` -> `Terminate R...`
or
`Session` -> `Restart R` (Ctrl+Shift+F10)

If nothing else helps, open the Windows command line and kill the `rsession.exe` proces:

```
> tasklist | grep rsession
# the output should be something like this:
 rsession.exe                  7260 Console                    1    166,144 K
# The number (7260 in this case; will probably be different) is the process id (PID),
# and you can use it to kill the process:
> taskkill /F /PID 7260
```

Caution: this will forcefully stop the R session, and RStudio will probably have to restart (this is what happens on my machine, at least).

Answer (score 1):

Using ctrl + alt + delete opens task manager and you can terminate the R session then restart it to continue working.